# Having issues setting array state of child component and passing it back to parent in a react quiz

Tags: reactjs, forms, components, parent-child

I'm a student and for my project one of my functions is a quiz. I am getting the questions from my backend, doing a componentDidMount inside QuizContainer, then passing each question down to QuizForm as props. Inside QuizForm I have 5 radio button for each question which represent a range from strongly disagree to strongly agree. When I set setState inside the child (QuizForm) component, it only registers the last onClick event and only sends that up to the parent. I think it might be rendering each question as it's own QuizForm, but I'm not sure how to gather all of that data inside the parent (Maybe as a state of the parent, but I'm not sure how I'd go about that).

Here's the code for reference:

```
QuizContainer

state = {
        all: []
    }

    handleSubmit = (evt, quizObj) => {
        evt.preventDefault()
        this.setState = {
            all: [...this.state.all, quizObj]
        }
    }

 render() {
        return (
            <container className="quiz">
            <h5>For each of the following statements choose on a scale of 1 - 5, one strongly disagree and 5 being strongly agree, and 3 being neutral. </h5>
                <div> {this.props.questions.questions.map(question => <QuizForm question={question} key={question.id} handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit}/>)}
                    <input form="quiz-form" type="submit" value="Submit" />
                </div> 
            </container>
        )
    }
```

```
QuizForm

state = {
        question: [],
        answer: []
    }

    handleChange = (evt) => {
        let name = evt.target.name
        let value = evt.target.value


            this.setState({
                questions: [...this.state.questions, name],
                answers: [...this.state.answers, value]
            })

    }



    render() {
        return (
            <form id="quiz-form" onSubmit={(evt) => this.props.handleSubmit(evt, this.state)}>
                <label htmlFor="question">{this.props.question.question}</label>
                <input onChange={this.handleChange}
                    type="radio"
                    name={this.props.question.id}
                    value={0}
                />
                <input onChange={this.handleChange}
                    type="radio"
                    name={this.props.question.id}
                    value={25}
                />

                </form>
        )
    }
```

Comment: In your `QuizContainer` you call `setState` wrong, also you are using `<container ../>`, is it a typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using map() method, which basically loops array, so yes, it is rendering each question as different form. You shoulnt put every question as different form, just wrap them all into one  and remove  tag from QuizForm.

Also handleSubmit should be method that submits form to backend (or w.e.), and create another method like handleChange or something, that accepts argument and sets state.

```
handleChange(questionName, selectedAnswer){
   this.setState({...answers, {questionName, selected: selectedAnswer}})
}
```

this way you can keep name of question (id or something like that would be better) and selected answer and pass it as props to your QuizForm (which also needs renaming to something like Question) and check the radio if it maches selectedAnswer prop.

Your current QuizForm component should look something like that (which also should be functional component, not class)

```
             const radioButtons = [{id: 'first', value: 1}, id:'second', value: 2];
              function Question({selectedAnswer, question, name, id}){
                 return (
                    <>
                   <label htmlFor={id}>{question}</label>
                   {radioButtons.map(({id: btnId, value}) => 
                      {<input type="radio" id={id.concat(btnId)} 
                        {selectedAnswer === value ? checked : null}
                        name={name} value={value} />})}
                  </>
               );
            }
```

In this example you have to pass question id, name, selectedAnswer and question to display everything correct. Id will be used for label, since it refers to element id, which has to be unique in every page.